# Was someone killed in the SpaceX Starship SN10 explosion?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, death

At timestamp 2:44 in this video:

There can be seen something that looks like a person on fire running and then falling to the ground.

Was someone killed or injured in this incident?

Comment: I'm sure it's not a person, the pad would have been cleared: I'd imagine it's a composite pressure vessel that's been breached and is tumbling.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody was killed in the SN10 explosion. The explosion was on the landing pad in the middle of a 5-mile exclusion zone.

Nobody was within 5 miles of this explosion.

Comment: Ten, it seems (SN10). Corrected.

Comment: It is generally considered very impolite to change a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. However, in this case, the answer is still the same.